# Make a Boolean Column based off of a categorical column with text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column of text called STATUS, that has one of four words. Active, Deleted, Changed, and Added. I want to make a second column called ACTIVE_YN. If the STATUS column has the word Deleted, then Active_yn should be 0, while all others should be a 1.

Comment: This site is not a great SQL design tool. It works best if you state your problem and show what you have tried, along with any messages, results, or errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a computed column to the table.

```
alter table t add active_yn as (case when status = 'deleted' then 0 else 1 end);
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems so simple now.

Answer (score 0):

You could add computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE tab ADD [active_yn] AS (CAST(IIF(status='Deleted',0,1) AS BIT));
```